# Magento2.3.0 In checkout page getting this error on console

Tags: error, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, console, loader

I have getting this error on checkout page in console. Also in chrome browser loader non stop loading but if i refresh the page two three time than loader stop loading.But if i'm going back to cart page then after again go to checkout page loader issue comes again. If anyone have idea then please reply. Thanks in advance.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
0a570bb380c548387637090f9034e701.min.js:13 Uncaught Error: https://XXXX.co.uk/pub/static/version1560436487/frontend/XXX/XXXX/en_GB/js-translation.json HTTP status: 500
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (text.min.js:8)
```

Comment: try to reindex, check magento mode. also apply permission to pub var

Comment: magento mode is production and all permission apply it

Comment: actually in chrome only checkout page loading loader non stop loading but if i try to ctr+F5 than loader hide it.but other browser working perfectly in chrome issue